# Install OpenCV faster - could it be transferred via a SD card?

Tags: opencv, setup, pi-zero-w

I installed OpenCV on my RPI 3, now I have the new RPI zero W, since I know installing OpenCV (let's say 3.0.0) takes a very long time, I wondered if I could somehow transfer my already downloaded (and installed) OpenCV on RPI 3 to another SD card that goes into the RPI zero W, so it will take much less time to download and install.

Can someone inform me if it is possible and how I should  do it?

Thank you, Dan.

Answer (score 0):

Yes Danaro you can. You can use [win32 Disk Imager](https://sourceforge.net/projects/win32diskimager/) and copy the whole SD Card contents as an img file and save it. It can also serve as backup and you can flash that img file into new SD Card of same or higher storage capacity.

Pitfalls:

- If you have used extra hardware flags when installing opencv like -mfpu=neon-vfpv4 it will not work in RPi Zero. RPi Zero only has support for vfp flags. The supported flags for any processor can be found out by

  ```
  cat /proc/cpuinfo
  ```
- If opencv is installed in generic way without any extra flags like above specified just taking backup of img file and reflashing it into different SD Card should work